# Add a controls instruction overlay to game HUD

Tags: unity, text, unity-ui, hud, tutorials

I was wondering how I could make an instruction panel for the users of my game in Unity.

I will add a photo to this post that shows an instruction panel.

Any explanations would be much appreciated!

[image: Instruction panel in corner of screen]

Comment: This looks like something that would be pretty straightforward to set up using a UI Canvas and the TextMeshProUGUI component. Have you looked at the documentation about the UI system and tutorials about making UI in Unity? What have you tried based on your research thus far?

Comment: @DMGregory I've thought about using a self made image. But the problem is, i'd rather learn how to do it correctly so i can save time instead of trial and error. The Unity documentation might be a good idea indeed.

Comment: @CezarP here is the official tutorial from Unity about the most common canvas components and how to use them. For a simple display you might want to take a look at the first three steps. That should be more than enough to get you started. When you encounter a problem with integrating it into your game, you can adjust the question with what you made and what went wrong. https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/ui-components

Comment: @Zibelas Alright, much appreciated.